# Encoding struct to json Go

Tags: json, go, encoding, marshalling

I have an issue encoding struct to json my code is

```
type MainStructure struct {
    Text  string      json:"text,omitempty"
    Array []TestArray json:"test_array,omitmepty"
}
```

type TestArray struct {
    ArrayText string `json:"array_text,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    Test := MainStructure{
        Text: "test",
        Array: [
            {
                ArrayText: "test1"
            },
            {
                ArrayText: "test2"
            }
        ]
    }
    body := new(bytes.Buffer)
    json.NewEncoder(body).Encode(&Test)
    fmt.Println(string([]byte(body)))
}

the wanted result should be

```
{
    "text": "test",
    "test_array": [
        {
            "array_text": "test1"
        },
        {
            "array_text": "test2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I do not mind if it's "Marshal" or "encoding/json"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To encode a struct to JSON string, there are three ways that provided by standard library :

- Using [`Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder) which convert struct to JSON string, then write it to `io.Writer`. This one usually used if you want to send JSON data as HTTP request, or saving the JSON string to a file.
- Using [`Marshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) which simply convert struct to bytes, which can be easily converted to string.
- Using [`MarshalIndent`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#MarshalIndent) which works like `Marshal`, except it's also prettify the output. This is what you want for your problem right now.

To compare between those three methods, you can use this code ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AC_4qccHTFL)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type MainStructure struct {
    Text  string      `json:"text,omitempty"`
    Array []TestArray `json:"test_array,omitempty"`
}

type TestArray struct {
    ArrayText string `json:"array_text,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    Test := MainStructure{
        Text: "test",
        Array: []TestArray{
            {ArrayText: "test1"},
            {ArrayText: "test2"},
        },
    }

    // Using marshal indent
    btResult, _ := json.MarshalIndent(&Test, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println("Using Marshal Indent:\n" + string(btResult))

    // Using marshal
    btResult, _ = json.Marshal(&Test)
    fmt.Println("\nUsing Marshal:\n" + string(btResult))

    // Using encoder
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    json.NewEncoder(&buffer).Encode(&Test)
    fmt.Println("\nUsing Encoder:\n" + buffer.String())
}
```

The output will look like this :

```
Using Marshal Indent:
{
  "text": "test",
  "test_array": [
    {
      "array_text": "test1"
    },
    {
      "array_text": "test2"
    }
  ]
}

Using Marshal:
{"text":"test","test_array":[{"array_text":"test1"},{"array_text":"test2"}]}

Using Encoder:
{"text":"test","test_array":[{"array_text":"test1"},{"array_text":"test2"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all I think you are going wrong on how to create a `struct in go`, as you can easily convert them to json.

You should be first making a proper struct then do `json.marshal(Test)` to convert it to proper json like:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    type TestArray struct {
        ArrayText string `json:"array_text,omitempty"`
    }
    type MainStructure struct {
        Text  string      `json:"text,omitempty"`
        Array []TestArray `json:"test_array,omitmepty"`
    }

    Test := MainStructure{
        Text: "test",
        Array: []TestArray{
            TestArray{ArrayText: "test1"},
            TestArray{ArrayText: "test2"},
        }}
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(Test)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("eror marshalling")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(string(bytes))
    }
}
```

Check this out on [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/cEHU3pidq26)

Answer (score 1):

I could not get the point you wanted to use `bytes.Buffer` if your objective is just to put the result into the console. Assuming the point is:

1. Create a struct instance (corresponding to a JSON object)
2. Emit it in the screen

The following code can help you:

```
package main

import "encoding/json"
import "fmt"

type MainStructure struct {
    Text  string      `json:"text,omitempty"`
    Array []TestArray `json:"test_array,omitmepty"`
}

type TestArray struct {
    ArrayText string `json:"array_text,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    Test := MainStructure{
        Text: "test",
        Array: []TestArray{
            TestArray{"test1"},
            TestArray{"test2"},
        },
    }

    res, _ := json.MarshalIndent(Test, "", "\t")
    fmt.Println(string(res))
}
```

`json.MarshalIndent` is used to make result pretty-formatted, if you bother it.